# Configuring Pulse Audio for easy use with multiple USB DACs?

Tags: pulseaudio

I have 3 Behringer UCA-202 DACs going into a mixer. I want something similar to this setup:

1. 1 DAC: Misc Audio to be mixed: output to go to the mixer.
2. 1 DAC: Audio In: Record/Broadcast: input to come from the mixer.
3. 1 DAC: Input to come from `AUX send 1` on the mixer, and Output to go to the mixer on another channel. This will be used for Skype.

I have one laptop, I want it to handle all of this. I can get all of this working properly however it takes *way* to much time for my liking. Is there anyway I can ease this process. All of these DAC's have the same USB ID, 08bb:2902. They're all plugged into the same USB hub though (which I keep on my desk). Further, I'll plug that USB hub into the same input on my computer. This yields static `device.bus_paths` in Pulse,

```
"pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:2.1:1.0"
"pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:2.2:1.0"
"pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:2.3:1.0"
```

Can I always associate a sink with a specific bus_path? Every time I plug or unplug the USB hub I get new sink addresses?

This would permit me to script the rest of what I need to do with easy `PULSE_SINK=`, commands.

Answer (score 1):

Your sinks will all have a property you can use to figure this out -- `device.bus_path` and `sysfs.path`. You can examine these with `pactl list sinks`.

In the ideal world, your USB devices will all have unique serial numbers which you can see in the `device.serial` property, which would allow you to identify the device regardless of the port it's plugged in to. Unfortunately, most device manufacturers don't bother with setting this to a unique value per unit.

Comment: Right, but is there a way to get a preset SINK, or must I figure out the sink on the basis of device.bus_path each time?

Comment: I'm finding that in PulseAudio 3.0 the bus_path and sysfs.path change. =/